# How to force download PDF attachment using Robot Framework + Selenium Library?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, content-disposition, firefox-profile

In my test automation suite I need to force download of a PDF file. The file in question is a PDF that has mime-type of an application/octet-stream, and furthermore, the server assigns

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
X-Download-Options: noopen
```

to the file.

When the link is clicked, a prompt gets in the way:

[image]

I know about the options that can be set when initializing Open Browser keyword so I did the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${PREFERENCES}    set_preference("browser.download.dir",r"C:${/}DL");set_preference("browser.download.lastDir",r"C:${/}DL");set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octet-stream, application/pdf")


*** Test Cases ***
Initial Setup

*** Keywords ***
Initial Setup
    Open Browser    about:blank    Firefox    ff_profile_dir=${PREFERENCES}
```

However, setting preferences like this isn't enough, the prompt is still there. BUT when I debug the automation suite and within that browser instance change the option *manually* for PDF files to "Save File":
[image]

It works. When the option is set, a file named handlers.json gets updated:

```
{"defaultHandlersVersion":{"en-US":4},"mimeTypes":{"application/pdf":{"action":0,"extensions":["pdf"]}},"schemes":{"irc":{"stubEntry":true,"handlers":[null,{"name":"Mibbit","uriTemplate":"https://www.mibbit.com/?url=%s"}]},"ircs":{"stubEntry":true,"handlers":[null,{"name":"Mibbit","uriTemplate":"https://www.mibbit.com/?url=%s"}]},"mailto":{"stubEntry":true,"handlers":[null,{"name":"Yahoo! Mail","uriTemplate":"https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=%s"},{"name":"Gmail","uriTemplate":"https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s"}]}}}
```

**How do I set the value when initializing Firefox using Selenium?**

I tried also creating a custom Firefox profile manually, then defined Selenium Library to read that custom profile on Open Browser but this is not a viable option because I don't want to store that custom profile in version control system.

Comment: While it is possible to use automatic downloading in Selenium, it is not adviced. Better (and cross browser) way to handle this is to use Requests library if you can extract the full url of the download. Get the url from the link, get cookies from the browser session, add those cookies to requests session and GET the file. After that, you can store the download to filesystem if you need to do something with it.

Comment: Quite true, but in this case I'm verifying that the link is working (check that a file with specific name appears in a temp DL dir) and the test where I check the contents of the file itself is done in another suite.

Comment: But you *are* essentially verifying a link when you extract the url from the element.  Consider you have <a> tag .. it has a ref attribute, you extract the ref attribute and just use that to generate a GET request with requests library.  Only difference is that its python code that generates the request, not your browser. Add auth headers from browsers session and what else would you need to verify ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to ${PREFERENCES} :
set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)